# How to stop the same package to be updated again and again in R?

Tags: r, package, pacman-package-manager

I always use the same script to update my packages before working. It works well, but for a reason I can't explain, when I rerun the script, the same packages keep getting uploaded again and again. And at one point, it stops.

Today for example this is the binary version of the `sf` package which is updated again and again. I tried to restart R and restart my computer unsuccessfully.

```
# ==== Option ====
base::options(install.packages.compile.from.source = "never")
rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("data_viewer_max_columns", 1000L)
base::Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")

# ==== Packages ====
packages_list <- c("arsenal"
                   ,"data.table"
                   ,"devtools"
                   ,"dplyr"
                   ,"ggplot2"
                   ,"ggtext"
                   ,"grid"
                   ,"gridExtra"
                   ,"gtsummary"
                   ,"here"
                   ,"jsonlite"
                   ,"knitr"
                   ,"lubridate"
                   ,"magick"
                   ,"moments"
                   ,"MetBrewer"
                   ,"pacman"
                   ,"purrr"
                   ,"readr"
                   ,"readxl"
                   ,"stringi"
                   ,"stringr" 
                   ,"tidyr"
)

pacman::p_load(char           = packages_list,
               install        = TRUE,
               update         = TRUE,
               character.only = TRUE)
```

## Comment

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:

   binary source needs_compilation
sf  1.0-6  1.0-7              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
```

It seems like this part explains why the `sf` package is updated again and again. `pacman` check for an update, I have installed the package `sf 1.0-6` obviously. But since there is a more recent source version of `sf`, `pacman` is trying to update the package, and since I set that I don't want to install packages from source, it updates the package from binary by default without checking if the version is the same as the one I already have.

Any idea how to resolve the situation ?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it to yourself by forcing it to install/update all, every time. I *suspect* (as I'm not the original dev) that the rationale could be simple: since it's feasible that you want/need to reinstall a package, then since you're including it you must know that you need a redo, so it'll do it.

Regardless of the rationale, though, we can filter the list to see what needs to be updated by comparing `installed.packages()` with `available.packages()`.

```r
ip <- installed.packages()
ip <- as.data.frame(ip[ ip[,1] %in% packages_list, c("Package", "Version")])

ap <- available.packages()
ap <- as.data.frame(ap[ ap[,1] %in% packages_list, c("Package", "Version")])
str(ap)
# 'data.frame': 22 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Package: chr  "arsenal" "data.table" "devtools" "dplyr" ...
#  $ Version: chr  "3.6.3" "1.14.2" "2.4.3" "1.0.8" ...

want <- data.frame(Package = packages_list)
quux <- Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, by="Package", all.x=TRUE), list(want, ip, ap))
quux <- transform(quux,
  broken = is.na(Version.x) & is.na(Version.y),
  update = mapply(utils::compareVersion, quux$Version.x, quux$Version.y) < 0
)
quux
#       Package Version.x Version.y broken update
# 1     arsenal      <NA>     3.6.3  FALSE   TRUE
# 2  data.table    1.14.2    1.14.2  FALSE  FALSE
# 3    devtools     2.4.3     2.4.3  FALSE  FALSE
# 4       dplyr     1.0.8     1.0.8  FALSE  FALSE
# 5     ggplot2     3.3.5     3.3.5  FALSE  FALSE
# 6      ggtext      <NA>     0.1.1  FALSE   TRUE
# 7        grid     4.1.2      <NA>  FALSE  FALSE
# 8   gridExtra       2.3       2.3  FALSE  FALSE
# 9   gtsummary      <NA>     1.5.2  FALSE   TRUE
# 10       here     1.0.1     1.0.1  FALSE  FALSE
# 11   jsonlite     1.7.2     1.8.0  FALSE   TRUE
# 12      knitr      1.36      1.37  FALSE   TRUE
# 13  lubridate     1.8.0     1.8.0  FALSE  FALSE
# 14     magick     2.7.3     2.7.3  FALSE  FALSE
# 15  MetBrewer      <NA>     0.1.0  FALSE   TRUE
# 16    moments      <NA>      0.14  FALSE   TRUE
# 17     pacman      <NA>     0.5.1  FALSE   TRUE
# 18      purrr     0.3.4     0.3.4  FALSE  FALSE
# 19      readr     2.1.1     2.1.2  FALSE   TRUE
# 20     readxl     1.3.1     1.3.1  FALSE  FALSE
# 21    stringi     1.7.5     1.7.6  FALSE   TRUE
# 22    stringr     1.4.0     1.4.0  FALSE  FALSE
# 23      tidyr     1.1.4     1.2.0  FALSE   TRUE
```

(`broken` is just provided as a check on `packages_list`.)

You would then replace your `packages_list` with the results from

```r
quux$Package[quux$update]
#  [1] "arsenal"   "ggtext"    "gtsummary" "jsonlite"  "knitr"     "MetBrewer" "moments"   "pacman"    "readr"     "stringi"  
# [11] "tidyr"
```

Comment: The solution is harder than expected, but it's clever and effective. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, that does not work. I tried to delete one package (`here`) and see how the code will run. I had to adjust your code since it does not take account of uninstalled packages : `update = mapply(utils::compareVersion, quux$Version.x, quux$Version.y) < 0 | is.na(Version.x) == T)`. It uploaded the package `here`, but for some reason, it also updated the `sf` package again which is not even in the list.

Comment: Okay, this mechanism does not take into account dependencies forced. Sorry, perhaps not the end-all solution you wanted. As for `sf`, both `ggplot2` and `knitr` include `sf` in their `Suggests:`, perhaps it is included that way. Does `pacman::p_load` have a way to not install suggested packages?

Comment: I do not know. But I think that the issue happens when there is an update available for a package in a `source version` more recent than the `binary version`. This seems to force the `p_load()`function to update the package from binary without checking if this version is already installed.